# Regex - select first html tag in line with string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which match the first tag in line with string "Apple"

Example:

```html
<div class="tn-atom" field="tn_text_1584898828640" target="_blank">Apple</div>
```

I need to select this tag:

```html
<div class="tn-atom" field="tn_text_1584898828640" target="_blank">
```

I can select all lines with regex `^(?!.*(Apple)).*$`

But how can I select only the first tag?

Answer (score 0):

`^.*(?=(Apple))` will select everything up until the last case-insensitive instance of "Apple"

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need to select everything, but only the first tag, because there may be other tags or words.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `^(?!.*(Apple)).*$` will match a line that does not contain Apple.

If there are no angle brackets in between, you can use a capture group and capture from `<...>` without any brackets in between followed by matching Apple.

```
^\s*(<([^\s<>]+)[^<>]*>)Apple<\/\2>
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T43Gxm/1).

The value is in capture group 1.

Note that this can be an [error prone solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) when dealing with HTML that can contain nested elements and `<` `>` chars by themselves. If you have the availability to use a DOM parser I would advice to use that instead.